# Show modal for Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to show a modal in an AndroidTV app. I tried following this guide in creating a subclass of a DialogFragment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.

I'm kind of confused because when I try to show the dialog, the example shows:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
```

But when I try, to create the FragmentTransaction, Android Studio wants to use what is I think a different FragmentTransaction.

```
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        android.app.Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        DialogFragment newFragment = CartDialogFragment.newInstance(111);
```

so then when I try to do `newFragment.show`, it cannot resolve the method.

My CartDialogFragment imports look like:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

Is there a different import I need to add to my Gradle file? Is this type of DialogFragment compatible with the AndroidTV leanback library?

Comment: Are you trying to mix support library fragments with fragments from the base SDK?  Don't do that, use all of one or the other (my suggestion would be all from the support library).

Comment: @GabeSechan Hi. I'm not trying to mix the fragments intentionally. I am just looking at this stuff for the first time. Is there a different type of DialogFragment I should use for TV?

Comment: Its not about TV, but its about the support library.  If you're using support library fragments (or support library activities) extend android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment  instead.  The support library exists to backport fixes to older versions of the app, and mixing the two leads to problems.  That also means using the support version of getFragmentManager, etc.

Comment: The reason I suspect this is that you declare android.app.FragmentTransaction ft.  Using the fully qualified name is only necessary if the name is in conflict, and that should only happen if elsewhere you used a support library fragment transaction.

Comment: @Crystal, did you ever come up with a solution? I have a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try replaceing `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`,like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
if (prev != null) {
    ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);

// Create and show the dialog.
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
```

Because your fragment extends `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`,you should also use a compatible version of `FragmentManager`.

Also have a look at [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment).

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() is not supported in the default AndroidTV app :-\

Comment: @Crystal Have you made your activity extend [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity) or [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity)?